# need help fixing a countdown clock with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, countdown

I am trying to create a countdown clock and have hit a bit of a snag. It is displaying the final number, the final result of the for loop, which I don't want. My goal is to have to for loop fire my .setTimeout every time it loops. I would appreciate any help.

```
const countdownClock = (ranNum) => {
    const startingNum = ranNum * 50;
    for(let i = startingNum; i > 0; i--) {
        setTimeout(() => countdownSpan.textContent = [i], 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the `setTimeout` is waiting for `1s` to execute and until then the loop is completed even before your first `setTimeout` triggers and when your first timeout is triggered the value of `i` is updated and is now the last number of the loop. You can handle it with the `promises` and `async/await`.

```
const countdownClock = async (ranNum) => {
    const startingNum = ranNum * 50;
    for(let i = startingNum; i > 0; i--) {
        await new Promise(resolve => {
         setTimeout(() => {
            countdownSpan.textContent = [i];
            resolve()
         }, 1000)
       });
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks so much, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Timer functions won't fire until after the current function is complete. This is why your `for` loop runs to completion before the timer function runs. In order to see the timer tick away, you shouldn't use a loop at all because the timer will create the looping functionality. You only need either a `setInterval()` or a `setTimeout()` that is recursive.

```js
const element = document.getElementById("countdown");

let startingNum = parseInt(Math.random() * 50, 10);
let timer = null;

function counter(){
  // Clear any running timer to prevent multiple
  // timers from stacking up in the event queue
  clearTimeout(timer); 
  
  startingNum--; // Decrease the counter
  
  // If the count is greater than 0
  if(startingNum >-1){
    element.textContent = startingNum;

    // Set a new timer up to call this function
    timer = setTimeout(counter, 1000); 
  }   
}

// Start the process off
timer = setTimeout(counter, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Scott, is possible that there's no exit condition for function `counter` and it never stop the recursive loop?

Comment: @Pierfrancesco I've updated my answer and moved the recursive timer call into the `if` condition that warrants a new timer to be set up. If you don't fall into that branch, you won't set up a new timer and the timers will stop.

Comment: @AndrewLovato You're welcome. Don't forget to mark this as "the" answer by clicking the checkmark at the top-left of the answer.